# Capistrano test run failed, but deployment successful

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jenkins, capistrano

I have setup Capistrano for my rails project deployment & I'm running my unit tests from a custom cap task as below.

```
namespace :deploy do
  desc "Runs test before deploying, can't deploy unless they pass"
  task :run_tests do

    puts "--> Running tests, please wait ..."
    unless system "bundle exec rake > log/capistrano.log 2>&1" #' > /dev/null'
      puts "--> Tests failed. Run `cat log/capistrano.log` to see what went wrong."
      exit
    else
      puts "--> Tests passed"
    end

    puts "--> All tests passed"
  end
end
```

If there is a unit test failure in the system, deployment will not proceed further, but in `jenkins` the build is showing in blue color. That means build is successful.

How can I notify `jenkins` that build ended with errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running `exit` in the "tests failed" branch, which ends the ruby program with a status code of zero (success!).

If you `exit 1` (or anything nonzero) from ruby, jenkins will know that something bad happened.

There are other ways to "exit unsuccessfully" in ruby (like raise), but exit works just like in bash.